# More precise version of Mertens theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

By Mertens theorem we know that
$$
\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log x +O(1).
$$

Is it possible to know something stronger of the type
$$
\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log x +A +E(x),
$$
where $A$ is some constant (and we don't care about the precise value of it) and $E(x)$ is some error term clearly better than $O(1)$?

Does a similar thing hold for a fixed arithmetic progression, say, $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$?

Comment: Sure [Mertens' second theorem and the prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#Mertens'_second_theorem_and_the_prime_number_theorem).

Comment: For $(a,q)=1$, the PNT in arithmetic progression says $\sum_{p^k \le x, p^k \equiv a \bmod q} \log p = \frac{x}{\varphi(q)} +O(\frac{x}{\log^k(x)})$ and under the GRH it is improved to $\frac{x}{\varphi(q)} +x^{1/2} \log^2(x))$. Partial summation and $\sum_{p^k\le x, k \ge 2} \frac{\log(p) }{p^k}= C+O(x^{-1/2})$ answers your 2nd point.

Comment: I don't see how it answers my question. The fact that $$\sum_{p^k \le x, k\ge 2} \frac{\log p}{p^k} \ll 1$$ is pretty clear. I am not interested in conditional error terms, but rather on understanding what $E(x)$ above could be. For example, could it be $E(x) \ll 1/\log x$? I clearly don't expect any power saving, but the logarithmic one (double log also works).

Comment: Mertens second theorem gives $$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log x+B+E'(x),$$ where $E'(x)$ depends of zero-free region for $\zeta$. I don't see how it helps me to get the formula above, since simple partial summation of the sum of reciprocals gives weaker result.

Comment: Also, I guess you have a problem in the PNT in arithmetic progressions, since the error term is $O_q(x/\log^2x)$ but not $O_q(x/\log^k x)$. Of course you can write the expansion by powers of log, but then you will have secondary terms.

Comment: See wiki (PNT, Mertens theorems, RH) $\sum_{p \le x} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log(x)+A+o(1)$ is equivalent to the PNT and $\sum_{p \le x} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log(x)+A+O(x^{-1+\sigma+\epsilon})$ is equivalent to $\zeta(s)$ having no zeros for $\Re(s) > \sigma$